# Difference between JQuery .show/.hide and CSS visibility:hidden

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to show and hide Div element with JQuery:

```
$("#Progress").hide("fast");
```

However I need the set the div #Progress element as hidden to start with.

```
     <div style="height:30px;margin-top:5px">
        <div id="Progress" style="visibility:hidden">
            <div style="float:left"> <img src="../../../../Content/images/ProgressSpinner.gif"/></div>
            <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saving.......</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It seems that if I use JQuery to hide it every time I load, I get a flashing effect as it keeps hiding it onload. So I really want it to be hidden until I show in JQuery.

I did try using the CSS "Visibility" attribute, but my JQuery .Show("fast") command has no effect on it, so remains hidden.

So what is the best way to default a div to hidden such that a JQuery .Show command can show the Div when relevant ie when a link is clicked.

```
    $(document).on("click", ".edit-link", function (e) {
```

Comment: `display:none;`. Try reading the docs, it answers your question http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: `visibility: hidden` still takes up space. `show/hide` set `display: none` which doesnt take up sace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. If you don't want to see the flashing effect, don't use the `.hide('fast')`.

But for your case, you could just do `$("#Progress").hide();`

On a side note, try `.hide('slow')` to see a slower hide.

b. `.show("fast")` has no effect because you have `style="visibility:hidden"` [which hides but takes up space on your page] on your progress div.

Remove that & replace with `style="display:none"` [hides & doesn't take up space on your page]

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the display property on your element:

```
#Progress {
    display: none;
}
```